# Finding Grade and Remarks of a Score in another table-MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL table called examrecords with the following;

`Studentid Score
1          60
2          70
3          80`

I have another table called grader with the following;

`Startpoint    Endpoint  Grade Remarks
80              100       A   Excellent
70              79        B   Very Good
60              69        C   Good`

I want to write a query that would pick individual scores in the examrecords and compare them with grader and assign the corresponding grades. Any Help?

Please use the following script to create a copy of the sample database...

```
CREATE DATABASE Grades;

USE Grades;

CREATE TABLE examrecords
(
    StudentID    INT    NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Score        INT    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( StudentID )
);

CREATE TABLE grader
(
    Startpoint    INT            NOT NULL,
    Endpoint      INT            NOT NULL,
    Grade         VARCHAR(1)     NOT NULL,
    Remarks       VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( Grade )
);

INSERT INTO examrecords
SET Score = 60;

INSERT INTO examrecords
SET Score = 70;

INSERT INTO examrecords
SET Score = 80;

INSERT INTO grader
SET Startpoint = 80,
    Endpoint   = 100,
    Grade      = "A",
    Remarks    = "Excellent";

INSERT INTO grader
SET Startpoint = 70,
    Endpoint   = 79,
    Grade      = "B",
    Remarks    = "Very Good";

INSERT INTO grader
SET Startpoint = 60,
    Endpoint   = 69,
    Grade      = "C",
    Remarks    = "Good";
```

Comment: Google and learn about JOINs in SQL.

Comment: I suggest that research into WHERE and BETWEEN is more appropriate - I can see no need to join here.

Comment: Yes that is what am looking at that is a where and between clause. But i can't figure out how to write it.

Comment: I have suggested an edit to your question that contains script to create the sample database (or something suitably similar).  Providing such script in a question clarifies the table structures being used and saves an answerer who wishes to test their answer a sometimes offputting amount of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT Studentid,
       Grade
FROM examrecords, grader
WHERE Score BETWEEN Startpoint
                AND Endpoint;
```

I have tested it against the sample database and it provided the desired results.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to add a comment.

Comment: Wow! it worked! thank you very much. I realized the problem with my SQL code. I tried using sub-query instead. This is simple and straightforward

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Please note, if this is a suitable answer to your question it is preferred that you accept it as such using the button / link provided.

Comment: Thank you.  Good luck with your studies.